Formation and Optimization of Dimers, Trimers, Tetramers, and Beyond
Can anyone please mension what is the procedure to computationally create clusters such as dimers, trimers, or tetramers for Quantum ESPRESSO calculations.

The dimer of what? Atom? Molecule? Is the cluster covalently bound or non-covalently bound?

@wzkchem5 Vanadium

Try basin hopping or minima hopping in ASE https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/optimize.html#module-ase.optimize.basin. You can start with a random arrangement of atoms spaced far apart
For small clusters of atoms (or simple molecules) it is probably okay to simply start from very many initial arrangements and minimize each one; cluster/remove duplicates and pick some number of the lowest energy ones.
A fast energy calculation should be fine for this, eg use the XTB calculator in ASE
